# Android Database Locate Data Before Application Starts

Tags: android, database, sqlite, select, insert

I need only select operation. Therefore the data should be inserted before the application starts. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an subclass of [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to access your db. The `onCreate` will be called once, when the database is created.

To use your db you can then do:

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper(context);
db.getReadableDatabase().query(....);
db.close();
```

To extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` do something like (the sql for the table creation is not tested!):

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
private static final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


/*
 * Called ONCE on the very first db access (when the db file is created)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mytable (_id PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, value TEXT); \n" +
            "INSERT INTO mytable (value) VALUES ('data'));");
}

/*
 * Called every time you open a database
 */
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

/*
 * Called ONCE if DATABASE_VERSION has changed since the last instantiation of DBHelper
 */
    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have more questions. I'm using a class like your DBHelper and in another class -which I called DBAdapter- I'm creating an instance of DBHelper like you did. However, it's called for every application start. I want to create tables and insert data once. How can I solve this?

edit : At method onUpgrade, I'm dropping all tables and calling onCreate again. Is this a problem?

Comment: It's totally ok to drop everything and recreate from scratch. And if you want to do this by calling onCreate from within onUpgrade it ok too.

Comment: Thanks but how can I avoid insert operations for every application start? I'm creating an instance of DBHelper in my DBAdapter and in my MainActivity, I'm creating an instance of DBAdapter.

Comment: onCreate() is called ONCE, when the database file is created! onUpdate() is only called once when DATABASE_VERSION has changed since the last start. And onOpen() is called every time your app opens the db.